# Dataframe_image OsError: Chrome executable not able to be found on your machine

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run my script in **Databricks** using **dataframe_image** library to style my table and later save this as .png file and getting an error *OsError: Chrome executable not able to be found on your machine.*
Per [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/dataframe-image/) I need to add table_conversion = 'matplotlib'

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
def highlight_max(s, props=''):
    return np.where(s == np.nanmax(s.values), props, '')
styled_table = df.style.apply(highlight_max, props='color:red;', axis=1)\
         .set_properties(**{'background-color': '#ffffb3'})

import dataframe_image as dfi # you might need to pip install dataframe-image

dfi.export(styled_table, 'file1.png', table_conversion = 'matplotlib')
```

As result all styles are lost.

Note: When I ran the same script in Jupyter using table_conversion = 'chrome' everything was working fine.
I was wondering if there is a workaround. Any recommendations are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Andre! Were you able to solve this? I am having the exact same problem!

Comment: No, Rafael. I had no luck with this. @RafaelPinheiro

Comment: No problem! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

For a Debian based os:

```
apt install chromium-chromedriver
```

Solved it for me.

[Chrome executable error #6](https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image/issues/6)

Answer (score 0):

This solved for me!

```
dfi.export(styled_table, 'file1.png', table_conversion = 'selenium')
```

The reference for other table_conversions:

```
dfi.export(
    obj: pd.DataFrame,
    filename,
    fontsize=14,
    max_rows=None,
    max_cols=None,
    table_conversion: Literal[
        "chrome", "matplotlib", "html2image", "playwright", "selenium"
    ] = "chrome",
    chrome_path=None,
    dpi=None, # enlarge your image，default is 100，set it larger will get a larger image
    use_mathjax=False, # enable mathjax support， which means you can use latex in your dataframe
)
```